# Frequently Reloading UITableview every second freezes the UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

Calling this frequently (every second) , after 5 minutes UI freezes

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Comment: It will. Why to reload all data of tableview. If you want to refresh visible cells then only refresh those cells or change your logic by which you can handle the refreshing as per your need.

Comment: why would you execute this code periodically? You should know when new data is available and only execute a reload than.

Comment: Better option would be registering the UITableView to Notification Center for  receiving updated record notification & then you can reload the UITableView accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the concern, but  i am getting data through bluetooth which i have to show in tableview. Data speed is so high , therefore  i have to add 200 objects in tableview every second.

Comment: When you receive data and add it to your model, you can post notification to which UITableView can respond. Just a though. With your current implementation, overlapping of reloaddata method is bound to happen.

Answer (score 0):

`reloadData` does not run asynchronously. This means that whilst you are correct to execute it on the main thread (all UI updates should happen on the main thread), the main thread will hang until the view has been reloaded. You are calling this so frequently that at some point the requests to reload start to stack on top of eachother, because it has been invoked again before it has completed. This is when the main thread locks up and your UI freezes.

You can force the thread to wait for the reload before executing another with

```
[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

but I would caution you in doing so. Instead, reconsider why you are reloading a table every second in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the answer . But i am getting data through bluetooth which i have to show in tableview. Data speed is so high , therefore i have to add 200 objects in tableview every second.